# jquery mapify the selection of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Use a plugin jquery mapify

```
<img id="Map-1" src="img_71.jpg" width="1050px" height="802px"  style="max-width:458px;max-height:350px;" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="269, 209, 274, 495, 150, 498, 148, 747, 33, 748, 31, 227, 158, 229, 161, 209" id="kv5" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  />
    <area shape="poly" coords="520, 503, 520, 748, 396, 748, 395, 778, 155, 780, 154, 504" id="kv4" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  />
    <area shape="poly" coords="768, 503, 768, 797, 649, 797, 650, 749, 525, 751, 526, 502" id="kv3" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="3" title="1-комнатная квартира" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  />
    <area shape="poly" coords="772, 283, 773, 796, 1041, 796, 1040, 611, 994, 611, 997, 287" id="kv2" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="2"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  />
    <area shape="poly" coords="495, 58, 496, 171, 527, 172, 525, 342, 690, 343, 690, 281, 1021, 281, 1020, 9, 894, 9, 892, 52, 540, 49, 542, 56" id="kv1" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" alt="1" />

$("img#Map-1").mapify({
    popOver: {
        content: function(zone){ 
            return "<strong>"+zone.attr("data-title")+"</strong>";
        },
        delay: 0.7,
        margin: "15px",
        height: "80px",
        width: "160px"
    }
});
```

When the button is pressed we need to select multiple objects. I have highlighted only the last in the list.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   $("#kv5").mouseenter();
   $("#kv2").mouseenter();
   $("#kv1").mouseenter();
});
```

Is there another way to select multiple items by id?

Comment: `$('#kv5, #kv2, #kv1').mouseenter()`

Comment: now select only the first  #kv1